# Determining integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Consider

$$2x^2y\ln(y)+(x^3+x)y'=0$$

> I want to determine the integrating factor $m(x,y)$ of the form $m(x,y)=m(xy)$.

Let $a(x,y):=2x^2y\ln(y)$ and $b(x)=x^3+x$.

So I want to find $m(x,y)$ such that $(ma)_y=(mb)_x$ where $(\cdot)_x$ denotes $\frac{d(\cdot)}{dx}$.

$(ma)_y=m_y \cdot x \cdot (2x^2y\ln(y))+m \cdot (2x^2\ln(y)+2x^2)$

$(m_b)_x=m_x \cdot y \cdot (x^3+x)+m \cdot (3x^2+1)$

We used the chain rule there. $m(x,y)_y=m_y\cdot x$

Now, \begin{align}(ma)_y&=(m_b)_x  \\ \Leftrightarrow m_y \cdot x \cdot (2x^2y\ln(y))+m \cdot (2x^2\ln(y)+2x^2)&=m_x \cdot y \cdot (x^3+x)+m \cdot (3x^2+1)\end{align}

Now what I don't understand is that they treat $m_y$ as equal to $m_x$, namely $m_y=m_x=m'$ and arrive at

$\Leftrightarrow m'\cdot(2x^3y\ln(y)-yx^3-yx)=m\cdot(3x^2+1-2x^2\ln(y)-2x^2)$

But perhaps this is wrong anyways.

I would appreciate it if somemone could show me how this is done. Also different or easier/faster methods are fine

Comment: The notation is confusing using $m$ in both. Say $m(x,y)=n(xy)$ instead. Then $m_x=n' y$ and $m_y=n' x$ so that $(ma)_y=n' x a + n a_y$ and $(mb)_x=n' y b + n b_x$. Equality of these gives an ODE for $n$, $n'(ax-by)+n(a_y-b_x)=0$. Everything works out if $ax-by$ and $a_y-b_x$ are functions of $xy$. If not then you have more work to do.

Comment: That said, consider backing up to a general $m$, so you need $m_y(2x^2 y \ln(y)) + m (2x^2 \ln(y) + 2x^2) = m_x(x^3+x)+m(3x^2+1)$. It would be nice to be freed of the log terms which would happen if $m_y=-m/y$. Then you are left with $m_x(x^3+x)+m(x^2+1)=0$ which is just $m_x=-m/x$. These equations can then be integrated.

Comment: It's a separable equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2x^2y\ln(y)+(x^3+x)y'=0$$
Integrating factor $\mu(xy)=\frac 1 {xy}$
$$2x\ln(y)+(x^2+1)\frac {y'}{y}=0$$
$$(x^2+1)'\ln(y)+(x^2+1)(\ln y)'=0$$
$$((x^2+1)(\ln y))'=0$$
Integrate:
$$(x^2+1)\ln y=K$$

---

**For the integrating factor** :
split the problem so that:
$$\mu (xy)=\mu(x)\mu(y)$$
Now we want to have: ( the derivative according to y:)
$$(\mu (y) y \ln y)'=\mu (y)$$
And also here the derivative is taken according to x:
$$2x^2\mu(x)=(\mu (x) (x^3+x))'$$
for this one I find that 
$$\frac {\mu(x)'}{\mu (x)} =- \frac 1 x $$
$$\implies \mu (x) =\frac 1x$$
For the other one I find that:
$$(\mu (y) y \ln y)'=\mu (y)$$
$$\mu' (y) y \ln y+\mu (y)(  \ln y  + 1)=\mu (y)$$
$$\implies \frac {\mu '(y)}{\mu (y) } =- \frac 1 y \implies \mu (y)= \frac 1 y $$
Therefore:
$$\mu (xy) = \mu (x) \mu (y) =\frac 1 {xy}$$

---

**You can also solve it the general way**
$$\frac {\partial}{\partial y}(M2x^2y \ln y)=\frac {\partial}{\partial x}( M(x^3+x))$$
We obtain here the derivative is taken according to $xy$:
$$2x^2(xy M' \ln y +M(\ln (y) +1))=M'y(x^3+x)+M(3x^2+1)$$
Rearranging terms
$$M(2x^2 \ln (y)-x^2-1)= M'(x^3y+xy-2x^3y \ln (y))$$
$$M(2x^2 \ln (y)-x^2-1)= M'xy(x^2+1-2x^2\ln (y))$$
It can be simplified as:
$$M= -M'xy  \implies (\ln (M))'=-\frac 1 {xy}$$
$$\implies M(xy)=\frac 1 {xy}$$

Comment: How did you find out the integrating factor?

Comment: @user728962 I added some calculations I did.

Answer (score 1):

This is a separable equation so integrating factors aren't necessary; we have $y'(x) = -\frac{2xy(x)\log(y(x))}{x^2+1}$, and dividing both sides by $y(x)\log(y(x))$ yields
$$
\frac{y'(x)}{\log(y(x))y(x)} = -\frac{2x}{x^2+1}.\tag 1
$$
Integrating both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $x$, we have
$$\int \frac{y'(x)}{\log(y(x))y(x)}\ \mathsf dx = \int -\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\ \mathsf dx,\tag 2$$
and computing the integrals we see that $(2)$ is equivalent to
$$
\log\log y(x) = -\log(x^2+1) + C,
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Hence
$$
y(x) = e^{C/(x^2+1)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$m=m(xy)$$ we have $m_x=ym'$ and $m_y=xm'$

The expression that they have is correct.

The question is that how does the expression help in finding the integrating factor?

Answer (score 0):

You are considering the equation $$2x^2y\ln(y)+(x^3+x)y'=0$$ Make life simpler and, to get rid of the unpleasant $\ln(y)$, let $y=e^z$ which reduces the equation to 
$$(1+x^2)z'+2x z=0\implies z=\frac C {1+x^2}\implies y=\exp\left(\frac C {1+x^2} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

and arrive at

$$m′⋅(2x^3y\ln(y)−yx^3−yx)=m⋅(3x^2+1−2x^2\ln(y)−2x^2)$$

But perhaps this is wrong anyways.

---

No it's not wrong at all.

Note that $3x^2-2x^2=x^2$
$$m′⋅(2x^3y\ln(y)−yx^3−yx)=m⋅(3x^2+1−2x^2\ln(y)−2x^2)$$
$$m′⋅(2x^3y\ln(y)−yx^3−yx)=m⋅(x^2+1−2x^2\ln(y))$$
Then factorize $xy$
$$m′xy(2x^2\ln(y)−x^2−1)=m⋅(x^2+1−2x^2\ln(y))$$
Simplify
$$m′xy=-m$$
$$\frac {m'}{m}=-\frac 1 {xy}$$
Integrate
$$\int \frac {dm}{m}=-\int \frac {dxy} {xy}$$
$$m=\frac {C} {xy}$$
Choose $C=1$ :
$$m=\frac {1} {xy}$$